# Seaborn catplot "TypeError: Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric", but Y is a float

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I am trying to make a catplot from a dataframe with the seaborn library. Unfortunately, I get the error ""TypeError: Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric", despite the y being a float.

I start from a series of pickle files and get the starting dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['W','FEATURE','RMSE','G-MEAN','KEY'])

for pickle_file in files:
    conditioning = pickle_file.split('_')[8]
    with lz4.frame.open(pickle_file, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            try:
                pre_df = pickle.load(f)
                for index,row in pre_df.iterrows():
                      if row['MODE'] != 'biflow':
                        w = row['W']
                        feature = row['FEATURE']
                        mean = row['G-MEAN']
                        rmse = row['RMSE']
                        df.loc[-1] = [w] + [feature] + [rmse] + [mean] + [conditioning]
                        df.index = df.index + 1
        except EOFError:
metric = 'RMSE'
final_df = df.reset_index()
mdata = final_df[metric].apply(pd.to_numeric)
final_df[metric] =mdata
final_df.sort_values(by='W')
```

This is my dataframe

[image: Dataframe]

Now I transform the x into categorical and apply the to_numerical pandas function to transform the column I need into numerical.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import math

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
metric = 'G-MEAN'

final_df['W'] = final_df['W'].astype('category')
mdata = final_df[metric].apply(pd.to_numeric)
final_df[metric] =mdata
print((final_df[metric]))
g = sns.catplot(data = final_df, kind="bar",
    x='W', y=metric, hue = 'KEY',
    ci="sd", palette="dark", alpha=.6, height=8
)

if metric == 'G-MEAN':
  for ax in g.axes.flat:
      ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
g.legend.set_title('Graphic')
plt.show()
```

The result, however, is not a graph, but this error.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11448/3378495013.py in <module>
----> 1 g = sns.catplot(data = final_df, kind="bar",
      2     x='W', y=metric, hue = 'KEY',
      3     ci="sd", palette="dark", alpha=.6, height=8
      4 )
      5 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in catplot(x, y, hue, data, row, col, col_wrap, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed, order, hue_order, row_order, col_order, kind, height, aspect, orient, color, palette, legend, legend_out, sharex, sharey, margin_titles, facet_kws, **kwargs)
   3790     p = _CategoricalPlotter()
   3791     p.require_numeric = plotter_class.require_numeric
-> 3792     p.establish_variables(x_, y_, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
   3793     if (
   3794         order is not None

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
    154 
    155             # Figure out the plotting orientation
--> 156             orient = infer_orient(
    157                 x, y, orient, require_numeric=self.require_numeric
    158             )

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_core.py in infer_orient(x, y, orient, require_numeric)
   1350     elif require_numeric and "numeric" not in (x_type, y_type):
   1351         err = "Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric."
-> 1352         raise TypeError(err)
   1353 
   1354     else:

TypeError: Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric.
```

This is my dataframe as text

```
10 PL [204.9658139414907] [] conditioned
10 IAT [63189.64585836619] [] conditioned
10 PD [] [0.8109978784077266] conditioned
10 PL [203.3947336485638] [] unconditioned
10 IAT [65405.16446149324] [] unconditioned
10 PD [] [0.8101584061664382] unconditioned
15 PL [203.15203517562838] [] conditioned
15 IAT [67322.70053635715] [] conditioned
15 PD [] [0.8147150217455429] conditioned
15 PL [202.99493438354995] [] unconditioned
15 IAT [67383.2060610718] [] unconditioned
15 PD [] [0.8136121699081311] unconditioned
5 PL [208.35534001310637] [] conditioned
5 IAT [67960.7221678817] [] conditioned
5 PD [] [0.8018226299431327] conditioned
5 PL [210.2413105366637] [] unconditioned
5 IAT [69444.490873865] [] unconditioned
5 PD [] [0.8025759697391006] unconditioned
```

Comment: Your columns are lists, which probable means the columns are string formatted lists. please provide the output of `print(final_df.iloc[15, 3])` and `print(type(final_df.iloc[15, 3]))`

Comment: In the post, I added the dataframe as text.

print(type(final_df.iloc[15, 3])) -> the output is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(final_df.iloc[15, 3]) -> [210.24131054]

Comment: Try `final_df['RMSE'] = final_df['RMSE'].explode()` and `final_df['G-MEAN'] = final_df['G-MEAN'].explode()` and there's probably no need for `final_df[metric].apply(pd.to_numeric)`. See [code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zre0N.png)